# Running a script upon OID GET

Tags: networking, network-programming, snmp, net-snmp, mib

I am trying to use NET-SNMP to run a little script and return the value returned by the script
I have my snmpd.conf file configured with the extend statement:
[image]

although when I query the device using iReasonings MIB Browser, I get this:
[image]

I haven't done anything to the default MIBs that come with the installation of snmpd so I think that might be the culprit, I just don't know how to define the simple value that will be returned by the script.

All my shell script does is call the below python script (supply.py):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)

GPIO.setup(23, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down = GPIO.PUD_DOWN)

if(GPIO.input(23) == 1):
    print("Button 1 pressed")
elif(GPIO.input(23) == 0):
    print("Button 1 released")

GPIO.cleanup()
```

So how can I make the snmpd run the script when I query the OID as defined in the extend command?

Comment: Have you tried all the tips in the "Debugging script issues" section of http://www.net-snmp.org/wiki/index.php/Tut:Extending_snmpd_using_shell_scripts ?

Comment: @k1eran YOU MAY HAVE JUST SAVED ME! I'll let you know in about 8 hours :D

Comment: So @Funkyguy, were you saved or not ?

Comment: @k1eran Oh! Sorry, I forget to give an update.  It turns out it didn't solve my problem although there was a fundamental issue with my MIB so it may have just been that.  Now that the semester is over, I may revisit the project but i'm taking a mega break from it right now, haha.  Computer networking just isn't what I do